# Is it possible to display image with loadDataWithBaseURL() method in android?

Tags: html, android, image, webview

I'm trying to display the content of a html file with the [loadDataWithBaseURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method in android.

I just have a String that contains the Html file data in one String called source and I then pass this to the method.

for e.g

```
String source; //contain html tags with images
View.loadDataWithBaseURl(null,source,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

The data displayed in view is fine.
My problem is if my html file contains any images then I couldn't displayed it?
how can I do that?

Comment: The code you posted won't work because source will be empty and View.load can only work if you have a View object that starts with a capital letter. But you say the view is fine therefore I assume that this is only sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it, if the images in the source use relative locations for the src then you need to set the baseUrl to the "base" of where the images would be located. for example, if you were loading google's home page from the source, it would look like this:

```
View.loadDataWithBaseURI("http://google.com",source,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
```

That tells the webview where the images will be loaded from.

As a side note, I do not think "file://" URIs works in the web view, for security reasons.

Comment: I use a file URI to load images into a webview from the internal memory and it works fine

Answer (score 3):

use "**file:///android_res/raw/**" as your base URL and put your files in **res/raw** in your project.

res/raw/index.html

res/raw/image.jpg

```
InputStream htmlStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.index);
Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(htmlStream, "UTF8"));

// read string from reader
String html = readFile(is);

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", html, 
                            "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want to use some images from the sdcard, then your code should be like this:

`final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "YourFolderName");
bookView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + path, htmlTextWithHeadAndBody, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");`