# call local image in drawable with html (WebView)

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked few times in forums, but in my code, i can't display my image. I think it's not the right method :

```
webViewContact.loadData(db.getParametres().get(0).getInformationParam(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

getInformationParam() recup the HTML code, like :

```
<img src=\\"file:///android_asset/logoirdes_apropos.jpg\\"/> <b>Test</b>
```

My image file is in drawable, how i can display it ?

Comment: go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069822/is-it-possible-to-display-image-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-method-in-android) hope you will get something. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

There are restrictions about the HTML loaded with loadData() can do. Suggest using loadUrl:

```
webViewContact.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + db.getParametres().get(0).getInformationParam())
```

You can try the following code, and your file will be at: htmlFile. You can certainly do it in UI thread for now, but you might consider to move this to a AsyncTask later in real production if the file is huge.

```
String directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("html_cache");
Writer output;
    try {
      directory.mkdir();
      File htmlFile = new File(directory + File.separator + "give_a_name.html");
      String content = db.getParametres().get(0).getInformationParam();
      // assumes default encoding is OK!
      output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(htmlFile));
      output.write( aContents );
    }
    finally {
      output.close();
    }
```

Comment: No, getInformationParam return the html code, it's not a html page, just code. any other idea ?

Comment: you can write to the share directory as a file, and try to load it from there?

Comment: I get the html code directly from the database, according to specifications in my training, i wan't to apply this without create a file before, but if i should... how i can do it ?