# Using webView's loadDataWithBaseURL not loading images from sdcard

Tags: android, url, android-webview, android-sdcard

I would like to set some html content in my webview with some pictures.
I've read on the internet i must use loadDataWithBaseUrl to do such a thing because i need to link the folder of images **(basUrl)** in order.

My html content nicely loads, i can even ran the javascripts perfectly, but for some reason **my images cannot be loaded.**

Somewhere i've read there are some security reasons and thats why i cant load images from sd card to webview and some says it can be easily done **via loadDataWithBaseUrl**, so i really dont know which one is true.

Here is my method i tried, maybe with some mistakes so dont be rude:

**I got my html file here:**

```
mnt/sdcard/com.mypackage.myproject/3/3.html
```

**My images are here:**

```
mnt/sdcard/com.mypackage.myproject/3/images/Cover.png
```

**And this is my content loading:**

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/com.mypackage.myproject/3", myHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

**In my html code:**

```
<img src="images/Cover.png" alt="Cover.png" height="820"/>
```

So as you see i give the baseUrl, and for some reason the webview cannot load my images.

As many said, this can be a solution:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file:/"+ base + "/test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html","utf-8");
```

**BUT, i have 700 different html files and there are many images in many different places... so i cannot modify the html code.**

Is there a way to link the image folder to my html files to properly use them as a baseUrl?

Comment: Have you looked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069822/is-it-possible-to-display-image-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-method-in-android ?

Comment: Yes but this question has nothing to do with sdcard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load the image saved in sdcard in webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051364/load-the-image-saved-in-sdcard-in-webview)

Comment: If you gone proper through comment also then that question definitely help you.

Comment: You have to use File Uri to load image in WebView.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your loading statement. You have to put `:` after `file`

```
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/com.mypackage.myproject/3", myHtml, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: It was not when I have given my answer.

Comment: Oh, okay. I misunterstood your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put full path of your image  into html.

img src="images/test1.jpg"

Instead

img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"