# Load image in html string web view android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-webview

I want to load an image in `WebView` in android, and I have:

```
public static final String URL_EMOTION_2 = "/sdcard/kingfisher_ph/e2.gif";
public static final String FILE = "file:/";
// Get the image url
String imagePath = FILE + URL_EMOTION_2;
```

If I use `webView.loadUrl(imagePath);` I can see the `e2.gif` loaded to screen. However, If I try to create an `Html String` and load to `WebView`:

```
String htmlString = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" alt=\"My emotion\"/>"</body></html>";
webView.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

The code above cannot load image, it show only `My emotion` `String`! What's wrong with my code? Thanks everyone!

**Edit:**  Thanks, I solved the problem above with `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(...)`.

However, I have one more problem that occur when I want to `reload` my `webView` (because sometimes, I want to change `htmlString` and reload `webView` to show what changed), it usually start a blank web page!! How can I disable it? Or is there any other ways to refresh the `webView`after I change the `htmlString` intermadiately?

Comment: try to use the method "loadDataWithBaseURL". See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444368/show-static-html-with-imges-in-webview/12446546#12446546

Comment: No problem. You can vote up the answer in the other qustion.

Comment: @viperbone can you offer me any suggestion for my edited problem? Thank you very much!!

Comment: May this question answer your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563325/is-there-a-better-way-to-refresh-webview

see part with: webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );